# Two parameter return in Mapping in Observable

Tags: java, mapping, rx-java2, rx-android

Is it posible to have a two parameter return in Mapping of object using Observable ?

Because right now I'm doing it like this

```
Observable.fromIterable(outlets)
            .map(outlet -> new Pair<>(outlet, Picasso.get().load(outlet.marker).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).get()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> {}));
```

Is there any option to do something like this ?

Comment: No, java has no multi return value

Comment: @DeanXu if that's the case I'll continue to use the current one. thanks!